# Whoa! How did the water not go flowing everywhere?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was building an elevator with water and all that, when I accidentally broke open the door, but water didn't flow everywhere! But when I broke open the door on the first floor, water came gushing out! Is this a glitch or something?
[image]

Comment: Good question, but geeze that's a dark picture.  I can barely make out what's going on.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot my potion of night vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the water on the first floor doesn't have anywhere to flow but out where the door used to be. This is because the block at the bottom of the elevator doesn't go down one. I would suggest setting something up like this to prevent that.

```
| {}[]
| {}[]
[]{}[]
[][][]

|
| = Door
[] = Block
{} = Water
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is a drop-off or hole near falling water, it makes a beeline for the hole instead of spreading. If falling water lands on a flat surface, it spreads everywhere (and by everywhere, I mean 7 blocks in each direction).

You can effectively trap waterfalls by letting them fall into a 1-block deep hole. It won't ever fill up or spread unless you fill the hole with a solid block.